# How to get the value of an attribute using XPath and Saxon

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon

I am using Saxon HE 9.6.0.6 and am trying to use XPath to retrieve the *value* of an attribute.

Given the XML and query below:

```
<Pol>
  <ISR>
    <Code Val='Test1'/>
    <Text Val='test 1'/>
  </ISR>
  <ISR>
    <Code Val = 'Test2' />
    <Text Val = 'test 2' />
  </ISR>
</Pol>

//Pol/ISR/Code[@Val='Test2']/../Text/@Val
```

This gives me the *attribute* ( "Val='test 2'") but I want the *value* (i.e. 'test 2').   I think I need to use xpath-functions, but not sure how to add them in Saxon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string(//Pol/ISR/Code[@Val='Test2']/../Text/@Val)` if you are sure you have only selected one or zero attributes or `//Pol/ISR/Code[@Val='Test2']/../Text/@Val/string()` to select a sequence of string values.

Comment: For some reason string() doesn't work.  I've also tried fn:string and importing the fn namespace.

Comment: Please explain in what way the suggestion does not work, i.e. if you get an error, if so, which one, how you use Saxon to evaluate XPath.

Comment: The result of Evaluate is null.

Comment: Ah ha!! Your question actually led me to the issue.  I was casting the result of Evaluate to XdmNode!  It seems an attribute is an XdmNode, but a value is XdmValue.  I've spent half a day on this and only just realised.